# Permanence of links to e-commerce websites

Tags: discussion

We're seeing quite a few links to product pages and pictures from external, commercial websites and I'm not entirely convinced that the links will stay permanent.

How could we ensure that the information in the link, pictorial or otherwise, persists long after the link breaks?

Comment: If it's an imgur image it will probably linger for quite awhile.  Anything other than that is indeed suspect for longevity.

Comment: If you find a dead link, try to edit the post with an updated one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things come to mind:

- Use a picture (referencing where you got it from) which will post directly here. This keeps the picture golden.
- When possible, use a Google search link (or your favorite search engine) instead of a link to a direct site. This does two things: it keeps the fresh links fresh; is brand agnostic.
- If in order to show exactly what you are talking about you need to specify a page, make sure you paraphrase everything over *here* you are trying to point to over *there*. Sometimes it doesn't make sense to copy *everything* verbatim.

I know I do what you are talking about quite often and see your point. Unfortunately, *we*, nor anyone on the SE network can ensure *any* links will stay viable. We just need to try and do our best.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. You pretty much nailed the points that I had in mind. Regarding pictures, one neat tip is to use the 'Add Image' utility to get imgur to create a new image with its own URL on the fly. This URL should hopefully persist for longer than an e-commerce image link.

Comment: @Zaid - Actually, if you use the image "adder" which comes within the SE answer/question sections themselves, SE grabs a copy of the image and stores it locally so it will never become stale.